# What books should I recommend to my client to learn about web applications?

Tags: client

We recently built a large ASP.NET web forms application for a client and the main point of contact has told me he wants to learn more about the technical side of web applications. He has no programming experience and has a primarily business background.

I have provided him with many online resources, however he would like to get some book recommendations. After searching myself, I can't seem to find any that fit the bill.

I am looking for a book that will:

- Provide a high-level introduction to internet tecnologies (HTTP, TCP/IP, servers, web farms, hosting, scripting languages etc).
- Cover issues that commonly affect the success/failure of web applications (performance & scalability, security, data integrity, server maintainence).
- Give a very basic introduction to web development (ideally in the ASP.NET world, but not important).
- Introduce typical web application architectures (for example describing N-Tier systems, SOA)

I can obviously find **tons** of books on each of the topics mentioned above, however I can't seem to find any that would be targeted at people that are not (would-be) web developers.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one? [Learning Web Design: A Beginner's Guide to (X)HTML, StyleSheets, and Web Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527527) by O'Reilly?

It covers most of your topics, but unfortunately doesn't really cover the programming aspect - just the scripting. A good start nonetheless.

Then, if he's still up for it, you can hit him with [Beginning Web Development, Silverlight, and ASP.NET AJAX: From Novice to Professional](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599594) by Apress, which would finish the job and introduce them to MS technologies. "It adopts a “zero to hero” approach..." which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I think the second one is probably most appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You might get better responses on ServerFault since you're asking about a book that mainly centers on server administration rather than the programming aspect.

Comment: Thanks spencer, didn't think of that. He also expressed an interest in understanding how the application works. We've provided detailed documentation of our system, however an introduction to the underlying architecture (relatively straight-forward N-Tier system - web UI, service layer, DAL, Database) is maybe what he is looking for.